# asp.net refresh grid without reloading page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, reload, page-refresh

I have a `Asp.Net` `Gridview` which is binded to a `DataSet` in the code behind file. This gridview binding happens on click of a button the page. But on click of that button, the whole page is refreshed... and I have pre-existing Asp.Net chart on that page which disappears due to page refresh.

Now, I can avoid this using a update panel.. but the button and grid should be in the same Div of update panel. For me, the button is somewhere else in the page... and the grid is somewhere in the bottom.

Is there anyway to reload only the grid without disturbing other elements in the page.. now please don't answer with updatePanel, coz I've used it and you know the problem. Please answer this if you've had a better solution or with `AJAX`.

Thanks a lot,

Manish

Comment: could you show us sample of your aspx file?

Comment: Isn't it easier to find out why your Chart is dissapearing and keep that somehow?

Comment: <div>

 <form id="formView" action="#">

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdViewList" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="Planned" Text="Planned"> </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Unplanned" Text="Unplanned"> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Button ID="btnViewNumbers" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Go" OnClick="btnViewNumbers_Click" />
</form>

</div>

<div>

 <asp:GridView ID="grdDefault" runat="server" Visible="false">
 </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Pleun - exactly.. that's the idea I had.. but how to do it??

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I can avoid this using a update panel.. but the button and grid should be in the same Div of update panel. For me, the button is somewhere else in the page... and the grid is somewhere in the bottom.

Not a problem!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function click(id) {
        var btn = document.getElementById(id);
        btn.click();
    }
</script>

<asp:Button id="btnToClick" runat="server" Text="Click me!" 
   OnClientClick="javascript:click('<%=btnThatLoads.ClientId %>');return false" />

<asp:UpdatePanel id="upnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        //Your grid goes here

        <asp:Button id="btnThatLoads" runat="server" 
          onclick="loadGrid" style="display: hidden;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And there you have it - a button in one part of the page triggering an async-postback in an Update Panel in a different part of the page.

Comment: hi Cosmic Flame,

Thanks for the reply. The thing is that my button has a onclick function.. like buttonSubmit_Click() which has all its functionality written. 
If I use a clientside function, how can I make the buttonSubmit_Click() function to work??

Comment: Set the onclick function for btnThatLoads to be your buttonSubmit_Click() function - the clientside code is just to redirect the click from a button that can be anywhere on the page to a button inside an UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I can avoid this using a update panel.. but the button and grid
>   should be in the same Div of update panel. For me, the button is
>   somewhere else in the page... and the grid is somewhere in the bottom

Just use triggers for your update panel

```
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
 ....
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```